# GIT and merge conflicts with CSS. Why does this cause a conflict?

Tags: css, git, merge-conflict-resolution

We seem to run into a lot of merge conflicts with our scss files on our project. What's odd is that these are often not apparently in conflict. For example, I just added some new CSS to a file, created a pull request, and we get this error:

```
<<<<<<< develop
=======
    ...the new css...
>>>>>>> bugfix/OurBranch...
```

I'm confused as to why git thinks there's a conflict here. It's just additional CSS, not anything being replaced. As the conflict error shows, there's not even code to show that's in conflict. Not even a blank line.

Is this an issue with our configuration? Is GIT just really bad at merging css?

Comment: I used to get that when different IDEs would edit the same file and use different line endings...

Answer (score 2):

There was likely something at that location originally, so it's reading a deletion on one branch and an addition on the other, but can't quite resolve them.

If you run this while you are in the conflicted state:

```
git checkout --conflict=diff3 <path>
```

It will check out a version of the file with the conflict markers showing the source, destination, and the common ancestor, so you can see what happened.

This will output something like:

```
<<<<<<< develop
||||||| merged common ancestors
    ...the old css...
=======
    ...the new css...
>>>>>>> bugfix/OurBranch...
```

You can also make `diff3` your default conflict style formatting by running:

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Comment: Oh! Interesting! I'll try that next time.

Answer (score 1):

I was having that problem with CSS specifically. Best guess was different line endings or tab vs spacing in multiple IDEs was the cause of the problem.

However, we found using `GIT Rebase` on a Pull instead of `GIT Merge` (default) solved the problem.

This may not be a great solution for ALL your GIT content but it did solve lots of problems with CSS.

You can do this time by time `git pull --rebase`

Or set every pull to use rebase `git config --global pull.rebase true`

**Just be sure you understand what [GIT Rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing) does before using this.**